# Postfix + Sendmail (Rails): Mail not being sent out

Tags: email, postfix

I have a rails app that is supposed to send out emails. It works on my other ubuntu server, but not on this one. Here's my mail.log in /var/log:

```
    Sep  4 15:48:56 web2 postfix/qmgr[27071]: 18B6F8A8FB: from=<orders@mysite-lehmann.com>, size=4447, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
    Sep  4 15:48:56 web2 postfix/qmgr[27071]: B84A78A8CF: from=<>, size=2844, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Sep  4 15:48:56 web2 postfix/qmgr[27071]: B1FA98A8E4: from=<mysite.notifier@mysite-lehmann.com>, size=14467, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Sep  4 15:48:56 web2 postfix/smtp[12151]: warning: per-session SASL client initialization: generic failure
    Sep  4 15:48:56 web2 postfix/smtp[12151]: fatal: SASL per-connection initialization failed
    Sep  4 15:48:56 web2 postfix/smtp[12153]: warning: per-session SASL client initialization: generic failure
    Sep  4 15:48:56 web2 postfix/smtp[12153]: fatal: SASL per-connection initialization failed
    Sep  4 15:48:56 web2 postfix/smtp[12152]: warning: per-session SASL client initialization: generic failure
    Sep  4 15:48:56 web2 postfix/smtp[12152]: fatal: SASL per-connection initialization failed
    Sep  4 15:48:57 web2 postfix/qmgr[27071]: warning: private/smtp socket: malformed response
    Sep  4 15:48:57 web2 postfix/qmgr[27071]: warning: transport smtp failure -- see a previous warning/fatal/panic logfile record for the problem description
    Sep  4 15:48:57 web2 postfix/master[1000]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtp pid 12151 exit status 1
    Sep  4 15:48:57 web2 postfix/master[1000]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtp: bad command startup -- throttling
    Sep  4 15:48:57 web2 postfix/error[12113]: 18B6F8A8FB: to=<lkies@mysite.com>, relay=none, delay=84547, delays=84546/1.1/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)
    Sep  4 15:48:57 web2 postfix/error[12113]: 18B6F8A8FB: to=<wilson@mysite.com>, relay=none, delay=84547, delays=84546/1.1/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)
    Sep  4 15:48:57 web2 postfix/qmgr[27071]: warning: private/smtp socket: malformed response
    Sep  4 15:48:57 web2 postfix/qmgr[27071]: warning: transport smtp failure -- see a previous warning/fatal/panic logfile record for the problem description
    Sep  4 15:48:57 web2 postfix/master[1000]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtp pid 12153 exit status 1
    Sep  4 15:48:57 web2 postfix/error[12113]: B1FA98A8E4: to=<engineering@mysite.com>, relay=none, delay=256639, delays=256637/1.2/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)
    Sep  4 15:48:57 web2 postfix/qmgr[27071]: warning: private/smtp socket: malformed response
    Sep  4 15:48:57 web2 postfix/qmgr[27071]: warning: transport smtp failure -- see a previous warning/fatal/panic logfile record for the problem description
    Sep  4 15:48:57 web2 postfix/master[1000]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtp pid 12152 exit status 1
    Sep  4 15:48:57 web2 postfix/error[12113]: B84A78A8CF: to=<inquiries@mysite-lehmann.com>, relay=none, delay=99654, delays=99652/1.2/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)
```

I'm really not familiar with postfix and how to configure it. I can `telnet localhost 25` with no problem. Can someone help me debug this?

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have seen the same kind of message ("SASL client initialization: generic failure") before and here's the configuration that is working for me. The options that made the difference are enable_starttls_auto and openssl_verify_mode.

This is the `config/configuration.yml` file of a Redmine installation. I am no Rails expert and am not sure whether the configuration is the same for other Rails applications - probably only for those using ActionMailer to send mails.

You can find additional information in the Rails docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration

However I just found out that the openssl_verify_mode option is undocumented and some information can be found here: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6508-undocumented-actionmailer-openssl_verify_mode-option

```
# default configuration options for all environments
default:
  # Outgoing emails configuration (see examples above)
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto: false
      openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
      address: your.mailserver.com
      port: 587
      domain: yoursenderdomain.com
      authentication: :login
      user_name: "username"
      password: "password"
```

Comment: Thanks. so where exactly do I paste this configuration? In my rails app? in which file?

Comment: I just updated the answer

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what the exact path is to edit that configuration file? I couldn't find the `/config` directory

Comment: The config folder is in the redmine app root. What rails app are you using?

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/entry/trunk/config/configuration.yml.example